# How to best generate script with data for system-versioned temporal tables?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, smo

In SQL Server 2022 I have tables with a column using the "GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START" feature for timestamps. When I generate scripts for these tables that include data, the insert statements don't work:

> Msg 13536, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Cannot insert an explicit value into a GENERATED ALWAYS column in table. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the GENERATED ALWAYS column, or insert a DEFAULT into GENERATED ALWAYS column.

I am left having to remove the columns from the insert statement or change the values to DEFAULT. Is there a better way to handle this either in the table schema or somehow generate the script excluding those columns?

I am using C# with the SMO library to generate the scripts programmatically but I don't see a scripting option that applies to these columns.

Example of table column schema:

```
[RowUpdated] datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL
```

How I am currently handling the script output:

```
var lScript = lTable.EnumScript(lScriptOptions);
            StringBuilder lOutput = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (String line in lScript)
            {
                lOutput.AppendLine(Regex.Replace(line, @"(CAST\(N)(.{1,40})(AS DateTime2\))", "DEFAULT"));
                lOutput.AppendLine("GO");
            }
            File.AppendAllText(aFilePath, lOutput.ToString());
```

Comment: Use UPDATE instead of INSERT.  The column is probably a primary key and you can only have one value with the key.  The row is automatically being created and INSERT will just add a new row with same key.

Comment: @jdweng INSERT is automatically used by the script generator tool in SQL Server. I don't have any control over that. The columns I'm having trouble with are not the primary key, and for the primary key it is handled by SET IDENTITY_INSERT (also automatically added by script generation).

Comment: What happens if you use `NoIdentities = true` in the `ScriptingOptions`

Comment: It insert initially, but then you are changing values.  You cannot insert a 2nd time if primary key already exists.  Use SQL Server Management Studio and check log file in explorer under Management to get full error message.  The SSMS errors are much better than the c# errors.

Comment: @jdweng None of what you are saying is relevant. OP has a temporal table with a `GENERATED ALWAYS` datetime2 column, this cannot be inserted into or updated. SMO should be generating an insert script without those columns.

Comment: @Charlieface I tested NoIdentities = true and still get the same result. It includes the generated columns and their current value. I actually still get the primary key with this option on which I am surprised about. A lot of those options have poor documentation unfortunately.